# How to convert into UTC time with params provided as below?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, utc

If date is provided as as `01st Jan, 2nd Jan`, it should provide me an output in `UTC` along with current year and time as well.

```
Output : 2017-01-02T06:40:00Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot only use `datetime` module since the ordinals are not handled.

But you can use a regular expression to reformat your input, and then `strptime` to convert it to a `datetime` that you can convert back to string using `strftime`:

```
import re
import datetime

str_date = "2nd Jan"
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

PATTERN = re.compile(r"^0*(?P<day>[1-9]\d*)[^ ]* (?P<month>\w+)$")
reformatted = PATTERN.sub(r"\g<day> \g<month> %s", str_date) % now.strftime("%Y %H:%M:%S")
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(reformatted, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
print date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

will output : 2017-01-02T09:03:54Z

Comment: Excellent, Thank You. Can you remove % symbol from Z in last line.